# Unable to error handle runtime error 9 for second time

Tags: json, excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a json code which looks like the following:

```
{
   "gstin": "32AAOFV7699A1ZR",
   "fp": "012019",
   "filing_typ": "M",
   "gt": 0,
   "cur_gt": 0,
   "b2b": [
      {
         "cname": null,
         "inv": [
            {
               "val": 17136,
               "itms": [
                  {
                     "num": 1,
                     "itm_det": {
                        "csamt": 0,
                        "samt": 408,
                        "rt": 5,
                        "txval": 160,
                        "camt": 408
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "inv_typ": "R",
               "flag": "U",
               "updby": "S",
               "idt": "14-02019",
               "rchrg": "N",
               "inum": "VTR/142",
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "cfs": "N",
         "cname": null,
         "inv": [
            {
               "val": 4745,
               "itms": [
                  {
                     "num": 1,

                  }
               ],
               "inv_typ": "R",
               "idt": "31-2019",
               "rchrg": "N",
               "inum": "BLM/35",
            },
            {
               "val": 3631,
               "itms": [
                  {
                     "num": 1,
                     "itm_det": {
                        "csamt": 0,
                        "samt": 824.53,
                        "rt": 5,
                        "txval": 32982,
                        "camt": 824.53
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "inv_typ": "R",
               "flag": "U",
               "idt": "12019",
               "inum": "BLM/1",
            }
         ]
      }
      {
         "cname": "as",
         "inv": [
            {
               "val": 16,
               "itms": [
                  {
                     "num": 1,
                     "itm_det": {
                        "camt": 408
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "inv_typ": "R",
               "flag": "U",
               "updby": "S",
               "idt": "142019",
               "rchrg": "N",
               "inum": "VT2",
            }
         ]
      },
     ],
   "cnr":"ja"
}
```

It looks fine until the value of a is 3 and i is 2
Where I try to access the value of next b2b.

What I have as in vba is

```
Sub Jsonread()

Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Dim jsonText As String
Dim jsonObject As Object
Dim item As Variant

Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\ret\Write.json", ForReading)
jsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close

Dim i As Long

Set jsonObject = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonText)
i = 1
Cells(1, 2).Value = jsonObject("fp")
Dim a As Long
Dim rower As Long 'Just a row selector
rower = 1

Do While i > 0
   a = 1
       Do While a > 0
           rower = rower + 1
         On Error GoTo Mainloop
        Cells(rower, 1).Value = jsonObject("b2b")(i)("inv")(a)("idt")
            On Error GoTo Mainloop
            Cells(rower, 2).Value = jsonObject("b2b")(i)("inv")(a)("inum")
            On Error GoTo Mainloop
            Cells(rower, 3).Value = jsonObject("b2b")(i)("inv")(a)("val")
            a = a + 1
       Loop
Mainloop:
            rower = rower + 1
            i = i + 1
Loop

outside:


End Sub
```

At first when i is 1 and a is 2 that is an runtime error 9 but the On Error Goto handles it. but after i=2 and a=3 there is no value in json and the on error goto should have handle it, but it doesn't. I have tried placing the On Error Goto in different places of the code, it simply doesn't ignore the error and run i=3 and a=1. Why is it so?

Comment: You are jumping `On Error`, but you're jumping into the "happy path" in an error state, while never clearing that error state: that makes the "happy path" intertwined with the "error path", and when you're in an "error path", any run-time error will immediately halt execution. You need to de-tangle the execution paths and make sure your error-handling code only ever runs while in an error state, and then `Resume` properly (*that* will clear the error state).

Answer (score 0):

Add a label under `outside`, call it `ErrHandler`, and make it `Resume` to the `MainLoop` label:

```
outside:
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Resume Mainloop
End Sub
```

Then change your `On Error` statements to jump to `ErrHandler`, and now all executable code in the "happy path" never gets to run while in an error state, and all executable code in the "error path" (i.e. the `ErrHandler` subroutine) now only get to run while in an error state: execution paths are sorted out and de-tangled, and everything should "just work" now.